# django regroup within a template

Tags: django, templates, django-templates

i have a parent child table such that

```
class Service( models.Model ):
  id = models.CharField( primary_key=True, max_length=32 )
  access_point = models.URLField( max_length=256 )

class Service2Service( models.Model ):
  id = models.CharField( primary_key=True, max_length=32 )
  parent_service = models.ForeignKey( Service, db_index=True, related_name="parent" )
  child_service = models.ForeignKey( Service, db_index=True, related_name="child" )
```

i want to show the contents in the form of html tables such that

```
parent 1
child 1.1
child 1.2

parent 2
child 2.1

...
```

so i have a view that gives:

```
relations = Service2Service.objects.filter( blah )
```

and have the regroup template directive, but can't figure out how to write the regroup to correctly provide the parent 'titles'. any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to try to get the relationship the way Django's ORM likes it

First, I'd redo the related_name so it is plural (minor nitpicky issue, but makes the code easier to read)

```
class Service( models.Model ):
  id = models.CharField( primary_key=True, max_length=32 )
  access_point = models.URLField( max_length=256 )

class Service2Service( models.Model ):
  id = models.CharField( primary_key=True, max_length=32 )
  parent_service = models.ForeignKey( Service, db_index=True, related_name="parents_set" )
  child_service = models.ForeignKey( Service, db_index=True, related_name="children_set" )
```

Second, Get a set of parent services in your view.

```
def my_view(request, ...
  ...
  parent_services = Service.objects.filter( blah)
  ...
```

Then once you're in the template you can write a nested for-loop:

```
{% for service in parent_services %}
  <tr> ... {{service}} </tr>
  {% for child_service in service.children_set.all %}
    <tr> ... {{child_service}} </tr>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The service.children_set.all command follows the relationship for you.

Comment: This is wrong. to access the backwards relationship from a service object, use what you set the related_name to in the related model. `children` not `children_set`. `_set` is the default if you hadn't set a related name.